# JavaScript - Can't add dictionary value to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Let's consider the following piece of code

```
        var array = [];
        var obj =[{id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}, {id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}]
        for (x in obj){

            array.push(x.name)

        }
```

I end up with array which has a proper lenght but is filled with nulls. I changed this obj.name into random string and everything worked perfectly fine. It's worth to mention that the appropriate code involves angular.js and I encountered that problem when iterating over a parsed json. But even when I pasted this simple array of dictionaries called "obj", the problem was still present.

I came up that the problem must be with pushing a dictionary value into array, am I right? If yes, what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're misinterpreting `x` here I think.

Comment: x is just a variable, could be anything else

Comment: No, I mean it looks like you don't really know what *your* `x` is.

Comment: x is a dictionary, an element of the array, isn't it?

Comment: Nope. `console.log(x);` It's the integer index into your array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, in code

```
for (x in obj)
```

x will be the index of each element in obj, meaning that instead of getting the element itself, you will get obj.indexOf(element).

In your case, x will be 0, 1. So x.name will be undefined.

Modify your code as this:

```
    var array = [];
    var obj =[{id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}, {id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}]
    for (x in obj){

        array.push(obj[x].name)

    }
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to iterate over objects instead of indices, how the correct for each loop will look like?

Comment: If the collection is an array then it uses index, otherwise for an object it uses field name as a key.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) for Array, try this

```
for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++){
    array.push(obj[i].name)
}
```

In your case you try get `name` in `x` but `x` is property name not object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `obj[x].name` instead of `x.name`. `x` in this case is just an index. `obj[x]` will return an item with index `x`, i.e. `obj[0]`, `obj[1]`.

And `x.name` is basically `0.name`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: alright, I thought that x is a dictionary. For each loops usually iterates over objects in array, don't they?

Comment: (for ... in) was never a great construct in JS, as compared to how it's implemented in other languages. AND, it has "hasOwnProperty" bugs. Don't try to make sense of it, just use other loop-iteration methods (ie, ".forEach()" or "Object.keys(arr).forEach".)

Answer (score 1):

For javascript dictionaries, I usually just use specially organized *objects*.  Since dictionaries should have only one entry per key, I assign the key to an object *property*.  Javascript includes a [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to get properties.

So the cool thing, is that you can just assign new properties and "index" using the properties:

```
var dictionary= {};
var obj =[{id: "id1", name: "Friend name"}, {id: "id2", name: "Friend name"}]
obj.forEach(function (o) {
    dictionary[o.id] = o; //adds more properties whose label are unique ids
}
```

And to pull from the dictionary, you can "index" using the key (id).

```
var id = "id1";
var person = dictionary[id];  //is {id: "id1", name: "Friend name"}
```

You can still loop through the dictionary by looping through its properties.